# Google cloud load balancer unevenly distributes traffic

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, load-balancing

I have created instance groups with 3 instances and GCP load balancer of type HTTP/2.
When I hit the load balancer's IP, the requests get randomly distributed say I hit 12 requests since there are 3 instances the load distribution should have been 4 per VM but it doesn't happen in a round robin away. Is there any possibility that I can achieve this in GCP?

Comment: Disable "Session affinity" on your backend(s).  Session affinity: https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/#session_affinity

Comment: My "Session affinity" is et to NONE.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. Were you able to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

The [algorithm](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/#load_distribution_algorithm) used by the GCP load Balancing is intended to distribute load according to the geographic location of the clients. If more than one zone is configured with backends in a region, the traffic is distributed across the instance groups in each zone according to each group's capacity.

The Round-robin algorithm is present only when you create a backend made of instances within the same zone; in that case the requests are spread evenly over the instances.

Comment: My backend instances are in the same zone i.e "us-east-1", still, the load balancer fails to distribute the load evenly across the instances.

Comment: Just as a clarification, "us-east-1" is a region. The [GCP zones](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/regions-zones) are typically named as the region but ending with a lowercase letter like us-east1-a, us-east1-b, us-east1-c, etc.

Comment: Yes , the insaces are in the zone us-east1-b

Comment: If your backend was made by three instances that belong to the same VPC, in the same zone and they are part of the same instance group, the round robin algorithm should be used according to the documentation. If you found something different you should raise a bug in [Public issue tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers). You only have to locate the hyperlink "Create new Cloud Load Balancing issue" and fill in the form to describe the issue you are describing.

Answer (score 0):

Beside Round robin, GCP has two mode

1. **RATE** for instance groups or NEGs, is the target maximum number of requests (queries) per second (RPS, QPS). The target maximum RPS/QPS can be exceeded if all backends are at or above capacity.
2. **UTILIZATION** is the backend utilization of VMs in an instance group.

How traffic is distributed among backends depends on the mode of the load balancer.

From GCP Documentation

> For both mode, The capacity estimation and the proactive assignment—influence the distribution among instances. Thus, Cloud Load Balancing behaves differently from a simple round-robin load balancer that spreads requests exactly 50:50 between two instances. Instead, Google Cloud load balancing attempts to optimize the backend instance selection for each request.

Read full doc from [here](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/#load_distribution_algorithm)